# D2L email integration using web service. Get all messages in inbox for logged in user.

Tags: desire2learn

Am integrating D2L using Java HttpClient. I called rest API to get all courses:

/d2l/api/le/1.0/97578/classlist/

In this am getting users email id null. I want to integrate D2L email using Java client. Do we have any API for integrating D2L email using Java client?

Answer (score 0):

For privacy reasons, the back-end LMS may be configured to prevent certain kinds of user data from appearing in the data retrieved in the classlist. This can include a user's email address.

It's possible, also, that the organizational unit (the course offering, in this case) has been configured not to expose users' email address through the classlist or similar API calls.